# How to make a single page installation wizard?

Tags: nsis

I made a python program and I compiled it using Py2exe and it works great.
As you know, all the big softwares shifted to 1-3 steps install. And many have just one page install in which they include their EULA. I found an example of this:

Image:

[image]

How to make just a single page wizard in NSIS ? Is it possible to do a single page installer like shows the above image ?

Comment: Your screenshot says step 2 of 7. Do you want the user to be able to change the destination folder on this page?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. the screenshot is just an example of that one page install. it won't be step 2 of 7 but rather 1 step.. when the user clicks 'accept' it will automatically install the software in program files .. No interaction in needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A NSIS installer is never going to be a one page wizard because the actual installing happens on a 2nd page.

There are probably two ways to create the every detail on one page wizard:

1. Use [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to edit the directory page in one of the NSIS ui's in NSIS\Contrib\UIs to add a richedit control and in the script use `ChangeUI` to apply this new page then at run-time use one of the license plugins to fill the richedit control.
2. Create a custom page with [nsDialogs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html).

Comment: Thank you so much Anders. how you think Download.com made that one page wizard? it works on all windows without any dependencies!